# Choosing "skip" and "Do this for all current items" in Windows 8 File Copy dialog

Tags: windows-8, file-transfer

I am trying to copy files off a bad hard-drive.  Windows occasionally opens a dialog to let me know there were errors copying certain files.

If I choose *"skip"* and *"Do this for all current items"*, will it skip **all** items and finish copying immediately?  Or will it only skip future bad files?  If the latter, will it also automatically skip other items that have different issues *(eg. require administrator permissions, file currently locked, filename too long, etc)*?

Comment: ROBOCOPY may provide a better alternative

Comment: ROBOCOPY +1 , which is windows built in function, but if you want GUI, FASTCOPY - a third party software which I am using is an option

Answer (score 2):

It will skip only future bad files (only same items).

Answer (score 0):

Due to my experience, it skips all items which have similar issue to your current file. For example I was copying files through windows to external harddisk. I used skip button, but then windows opened a box that this file name is too long and can't be copied, u want skip or try again. So I beleive windows categorizing files. If u skip, it all happens to same category files in future.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing 'skip' and 'do this for every occurrence will skip the files that cannot be copy or need permissions without asking you anything. When I am trying to save data from one disk to another I am using Total Commander because if, for some reason, the copy process will stop working in the middle of action you won't loose data that was already transferred.